# JQuery-Ajax headers issue

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, http-headers

I got a problem with the headers when i'm trying to do a POST Request with JSON
This is the code:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: jsonData,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Fail");
                },
                success: function(){
                    alert("Success");
                }
            });
```

And this are the Request Headers displayed by Firebug.

```
OPTIONS /path HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.15.109:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0 FirePHP/0.7.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: http://localhost
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
x-insight: activate
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

And the Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Thu, 24 May 2012 19:17:01 GMT
Allow: OPTIONS,POST
```

As you can see, the headers doesnt match with the ones im specifying, but when i use CURL the Headers are this ones instead:

```
POST /path HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.25.0 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.25.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8u zlib/1.2

Host: localhost:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 5
```

Any idea or solution for this?

I also modified JQuery Source to set default values of the Headers sent by Ajax to JSON, but didnt work.

Comment: What do you get in the console if you log xhrObj within the beforeSend function call?  console.log(xhrObj).  Does it show that those properties were actually set?

Comment: Why do you want to set the "Accept" explicitly? The `*/*` in "Accept" header of Firefox says it can accept response in any format. Refer link - http://www.gethifi.com/blog/browser-rest-http-accept-headers

Comment: I think perhaps your issue may instead be the way your server is configured may not be issuing the correct header to the response.

Comment: @ariestav I got 4 empty variables and the functions that are allowed withing the xhrObj.

Comment: @user1169578 But why would it not issue the correct headers? CURL and a JavaClient worked perfectly. And cant be a Cross-Domain problem 'cause everything its on the same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it was a cross Domain problem, I defined my URL as an IP, so the browser interpreted it like a Cross Domain request.

Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a *same-origin policy* issue. Using `dataType='jsonp'` should work, but this might require other changes.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control for an in-depth explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the Server doesnt allow GET, so i need to use POST for this an JSONP wont allow me to do this.

Comment: I dont think its a CrossDomain problem, everything its running on the same server.