# CouchdB Jquery Ajax POST CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, couchdb, cors

I am prototyping a very simple webapp. I installed Couch 1.3.1 today and created a database. I am attempting to save a document to my local couch (localhost:5984) with a POST from a client browser also on localhost, but different port (6789)

```
var dbIp = "http://localhost:5984/commute";
var data = {state:0,timestamp:"faketime"};
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  crossDomain: true,
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: dbIp,
  data: data,
  success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5984/commute-tracker. Origin http://localhost:6789 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I have modified the local.ini to enable CORS as outlined in the [couchdb spec](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/cors.html) with

```
[httpd]
enable_cors = true
[cors]
origins = *
[cors]
methods = GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
```

I can see all of these changes reflected in the config file in futon. I have also tested the database with a curl:

```
curl -X POST localhost:5984/commute -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"tags":"sure","name":"made it"}'
```

The curl works just fine, but I can't make a similar POST in the browser because of Access Control Allow Origin. What else am I missing, or what can I change to make this POST possible?

Comment: I don't think jquery supports CORS because IE7,8 and 9 don't support it very well. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I am using jquery 1.10.1

Comment: When you open the url in the browser (Chrome) you should be able to see the response headers in the network tab (press F12 to open dev tools), make sure it has the correct cors. I think you're using Chrome already since the error looks like an error Chrome would give you. JQuery should work with cors as long as you're not using IE<9

Comment: Ya, I see the OPTIONS "pre-flight" request with expected headers and the response has: 'Allow: DELETE, GET, HEAD, POST' 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate' but it gives me a 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: Is content-length calculated correctly as curl does?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery-Ajax headers issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744326/jquery-ajax-headers-issue)

Comment: You should try to add `headers = accept, authorization, content-type, origin` to the `[cors]` section of your CouchDB settings. That is the union of headers that appeared to be needed for Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Going about this trying to do cross-domain, whether it's CORS or JSONP is not ideal.

Since you actually do control both the web server instance and the couchdb instance (I'm assuming you have admin rights to the server) I'd recommend using a reverse proxy to serve couchdb as an endpoint for the main web app.

If you're using Apache [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) will allow you to do this, or nginx is another great HTTP reverse proxy server...inserting a config directive like:

`ProxyPass     /couch_db/     http://www.localhost:5984/` (for mod_proxy)

would let you post to `http://localhost:6789/couch_db/commute`

Comment: * although posting directly to couch is possible for POC applications, I'd also HIGHLY recommend inserting at least one other layer of abstraction from your presentation using node.js, PHP, or some other rapidly setup server language to transact via an API that you can use as a gate keeper (validation, auth, etc) for your db.